# On-Going / Long Running Game

Tags: recommendations

Are there any Board or Card games that can be played where not players are not required to be there at the games start in order to play? I'm thinking a game that runs similar to an MMORPG where anyone can pull up a chair, play for awhile, and leave again without upsetting the flow of the game and still enjoying a decent, well-thought-out game.

Comment: Is the intention that it's a long-form game, rather than something short like President or Uno where you can add or remove players between hands?

Comment: I would like to find a game that I could setup for a large party where people can join in or take off without disrupting the flow of the game...